# SIGSEGV - Crash on pthread_mutex_lock ()

Tags: sql, c, proc

i am currently executing a Pro*c code, where the pro*c shared library called from the parent program.

On certain scenario the shared library is crashing upon executing an embedded SQL statement.

I tried to debug the crash using the GDB command and found out it crashing when `Pthread_mutex_lock()` from `/lib/libpthread.so.0`.

I am not sure how to fix or the solution any help will be much appreciated.

Below is the error

> 7124    in imo4020.c
>   (gdb) c
>   Continuing.
>
> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   0xf629a31d in pthread_mutex_lock () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
>   (gdb)

```
 EXEC SQL
       SELECT COUNT(*)
       INTO   :WSS_COUNT
       FROM   <Table_Name>
       WHERE  <Column1>             = :<Column1_HostVariable>            AND
              <Column2>          = :<Column2_HostVariable>         AND
              <Column3>   = :<Column3_HostVariable>                    AND
              <Column4>         = :<Column4_HostVariable>          AND
             <Column5>             = :<Column5_HostVariable>;
```

Comment: You have not found a bug in `libpthread.so` nor in `pthread_mutex_lock()`.  Your program almost certainly corrupts memory through something like buffer overflow, freeing memory more than once, or modifying already-freed memory,

Comment: To Add: The above mentioned embedded SQL is in a separate user defined function, during 1st function call, the SQL is executing is well and good and during the 2nd function call the crash is occurring and that too very rare scenario this crash is occurring.                                                                               the Program is running in x86_64 linux architecture and 11g Oracle DB

Comment: post a [mcve].   posting an unrelated single line of the source code or posting the 'select' statement (which is also unrelated to the problem)  does not convey enough information for anyone to pinpoint the problem source.